# Creating a haptic-touch-like button in Swift/Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've been playing around with an idea for a button which, when held, expands to reveal other buttons (like the FAB in Android). Without releasing, sliding one's finger down should highlight other buttons, similar to haptic touch's behaviour.

Here's a crude mockup I've created using Drama: https://youtu.be/Iam8Gjv3gqM.

There should also be an option to have a label horizontally next to each button, and the order of buttons should be as shown (with the selected button at the top instead of its usual position).

I already have a class for each button (seen below), but do not know how to achieve this layout/behaviour.

```swift
class iDUButton: UIButton {
    init(image: UIImage? = nil) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
        if let image = image {
            setImage(image, for: .normal)
        }
        backgroundColor = .secondarySystemFill
        layer.cornerRadius = 15
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
}

class iDUBadgeButton: iDUButton {
    var badgeLabel = UILabel()
    var badgeCount = 0

    override init(image: UIImage? = nil) {
        super.init(image: image)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        badgeLabel.textColor = .white
        badgeLabel.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        badgeLabel.textAlignment = .center
        badgeLabel.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1)
        badgeLabel.alpha = 0
        updateBadge()
        addSubview(badgeLabel)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        badgeLabel.sizeToFit()
        let height = max(18, badgeLabel.frame.height + 5.0)
        let width = max(height, badgeLabel.frame.width + 10.0)
        badgeLabel.frame = CGRect(x: frame.width - 5, y: -badgeLabel.frame.height / 2, width: width, height: height);
        badgeLabel.layer.cornerRadius = badgeLabel.frame.height / 2;
        badgeLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    }

    func setBadgeCount(badgeCount: Int) {
        self.badgeCount = badgeCount;
        self.updateBadge()
    }

    func updateBadge() {
        if badgeCount != 0 {
            badgeLabel.text = "\(badgeCount)"
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.badgeLabel.alpha = self.badgeCount == 0 ? 0 : 1
        })
        layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

If anyone could help with achieving this layout, I'd be very grateful! Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm developing the UI in Swift, but will be converting it to Objective-C once complete. If you're interested, the use case is to adapt the button in the top-left of [this](https://github.com/jacobcxdev/iDunnoU) to offer a selection of different tags.